# How do I create a row when grep doesn't find a match?

Tags: r, ms-word, docx, rbind

After a decade of lurking on stack overflow, I'm finally dipping in my toes to ask for help! Apologies for any mistakes!

I'm extracting tables from word to create my own data frame. There's about 50 documents, all with the same table, but the data isn't mine, and is a little messy, to put it mildly.
The table is 2 columns (Name, Values) by 60 rows, and df$Name contents are often written wrongly, or rows are missing all together. This is not my data, so editing it is not an option.

My problem is - I want to bind each word docs' data together, so they need to have the same columns. I will be transposing the data so Name becomes the header, Value becomes row 1. Because the df$Name contents are messy, I used grep to extract those rows I wanted. (previously I tried extracting but row number, but the row numbers changed between word docs)

These are all the values in df$Name that *should* be present.

```
Col <- c("Top Film / Web code (if applicable)", "Base Film / Web code (if applicable)", "Top Label / Sleeves  code", "Base Label  code", "Promotional Label code", "Trays Code", "SRP code", "SRP label code", "Packing format (overwrap, MAP, VAC)", "Vac pressure (if applicable)", "Die set", "Optimal running speed (max)", "Gas mix (if applicable)", "Pressure for Leaker checks (bar)", "Frequency of checks", "Metal Detection Limits", "No. of Units per pack","Pack weight", "Claims", "Shelf Life Of Product From Pack / Slice",  "Date code format", "Health Mark", "UK & EU Address","“e” mark present", "Weight present", "Top Label Placement", "Base Label Placement", "Promo Label Placement",  "Barcode (if applicable)", "No. of Packs per SRP/Basket","Weight of outercase", "Max No. of SRP/Baskets per pallet")
  
##use grep to get R to search for similar words present in all word docs################

toMatch <- c("Top Film","Base Film", "Top Label", "Base Label", "Promotional", "Trays", "SRP","Packing format", "Vac pressure", "Die set", "Optimal running speed", "Gas mix",
"Pressure", "Frequency", "Metal Detection Limits", "per pack",
"Pack weight",
"Claims", "Shelf Life",  "Date code", "Health", "Address",
"“e”", "Weight present", "Top Label Place", "Base Label Place", "Promo Label Place",  "Barcode","No. of Packs","outercase", "Max No.")
  
tab_select <- unique (df[grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), 
               df$Name, ignore.case=TRUE),])
```

Using grep like this is pretty successful - but if a value is missing, there's no sign of it - So in this case "Trays Code" was not present - but I need a blank "Trays Code" (with NA in Value) to be created. Adding one in doesn't help, as it's at the bottom of the table, and I need them to stay in the right order.

Is there a way to get grep to match, but also create a row with NA if there are no matches?

---

I tried making a separate table with the correct column names - using dplyr to join, hoping any duplicates would disappear, but the slightly differing names in df$Name and Col mean more duplicates.

I'm not sure if I should be looping through each pattern and creating a row if there's no much - I'm just wary of making loops in loops in loops, which could happen.
ATM, this one grep formula is using multiple patterns, and some patterns pick up multiple rows of data, which might complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```r
df <- data.frame(Name =  c("Top Film / Web code (if applicable)", "Base Film / Web code (if applicable)", "Top Label / Sleeves code", "Base Label code", "Promotional Label code", "Trays Code", "SRP code", "SRP label code", "Packing format (overwrap, MAP, VAC)", "Vac pressure (if applicable)", "Die set", "Optimal running speed (max)", "Gas mix (if applicable)", "Pressure for Leaker checks (bar)", "Frequency of checks", "Metal Detection Limits", "No. of Units per pack","Pack weight", "Claims", "Shelf Life Of Product From Pack / Slice", "Date code format", "Health Mark", "UK & EU Address","“e” mark present", "Weight present", "Top Label Placement", "Base Label Placement", "Promo Label Placement", "Barcode (if applicable)", "No. of Packs per SRP/Basket","Weight of outercase", "Max No. of SRP/Baskets per pallet"))

toMatch <- c("Top Film","Base Film", "Top Label", "Base Label", "Promotional", "Trays", "SRP","Packing format", "Vac pressure", "Die set", "Optimal running speed", "Gas mix", "Pressure", "Frequency", "Metal Detection Limits", "per pack", "Pack weight", "Claims", "Shelf Life", "Date code", "Health", "Address", "“e”", "Weight present", "Top Label Place", "Base Label Place", "Promo Label Place", "Barcode","No. of Packs","outercase", "Max No.")

df$Value <- 1:nrow(df)
df$Name[6] <- "Not Matched"
out <- lapply(toMatch, function(x){
  if(any(grepl(x, df$Name))){
    df[grep(x, df$Name), ]
  }else{
    data.frame(Name = x, Value=NA)
  }
})

out <- do.call(rbind, out)
head(out, n=10)
#>                                     Name Value
#> 1    Top Film / Web code (if applicable)     1
#> 2   Base Film / Web code (if applicable)     2
#> 3               Top Label / Sleeves code     3
#> 26                   Top Label Placement    26
#> 4                        Base Label code     4
#> 27                  Base Label Placement    27
#> 5                 Promotional Label code     5
#> 110                                Trays    NA
#> 7                               SRP code     7
#> 8                         SRP label code     8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that I changed the sixth observation of `Name` in `df` to `"Not Matched"` to show what happens when there is no match.  It is a match for `"Trays"` in the original data. You can see what happens with no match on line 6 of the output.

Comment: Thanks so much for this - solved my problem completely! I just used my existing dataframe, and all the proper values (in addition to the new NA) are slotted into the correct place!